# Why do cars "sway" back and forth?

Tags: controllers, grid

In Codemasters' GRiD, all the cars seem to "sway" back and forth slightly on straightaways, with no control input. Is this normal?

**Edit:** After more experimenting (I didn't have the game installed when I originally asked), the sway only happens when you just finish steering, like when you come out of a corner. There's sort of a pendulum effect. Even when your wheel is centered, the in-game wheel sways back and forth, less and less each time, until it eventually stops. I've confirmed that this doesn't happen when the game is played with the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

I've just installed GRiD again to check that, and I didn't see any of that behavior. Do you have a Gamepad enabled? If you have a Gamepad enabled, it might be possible that your analog stick is slightly sluggish, "swaying back and forth" on it's on a tiny bit. In case you do have one plugged in, try unplugging it and test it without any additional input device.

Comment: I use a wheel, but now that I know it might just be me I can play around with the settings. Thanks for going to the trouble of installing it!

Answer (score 0):

My copy of this game doesn't do that. I'm playing with a Logitech steering wheel on Windows.

Comment: Which wheel? I have a Driving Force GT.

Comment: Oops, sorry, forgot to include that in my answer. I'm using Logitech's G27.